# group_concat: have values display in a new line on the browser

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have a simple query that i'm using MYSQL'S GROUP_CONCAT() function:

```
SELECT `ProductID` , GROUP_CONCAT( Description
SEPARATOR "\n" ) AS description
FROM Features
GROUP BY `ProductID`
```

The above query works fine on the phpmyadmin interface i.e. the values are returned displayed in a new line as shown below:

[image]

However, when i run the query in the browser, the values are separated by a space and not in a new line as i would wish:

[image]

i should mention i have even tried using the **br** tags as the separator `(GROUP_CONCAT( Features.Description SEPARATOR  "<br>" ))`

but still doesn't display the values in a new line.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: treat the mysql daemon as a data-store, not an html rendering apache engine. You will probably note that in your technology stack, there is something sitting between your browser, and the sql server

Comment: Hey Drew. could you kindly elaborate what you mean there?

Comment: What does your browser connect to. You said browser in your title

Comment: I mean when i execute the above query inside a php script and run it from my server in a browser, i want it to display the values for 'description' in a new line

Comment: echo "Hi Joe<br>";  echo "Hi back on a new line<br>";  echo "1<br>2<br>";

Comment: the point being, have PHP do the formatting, that is what layers are for. Have it do the `<br>` or `<br/>`. Mysql should not be treated like a window dressing report engine. You may have thousands of users banking on it for it resiliency, high-performance transactional system, and Stan in Accounting wants to clog it down (ok, exaggeration) with pretty printing.

Comment: if you have to wedge a <br> in there, so be it. But just keep it in mind

Comment: you're right Drew. Separation of layers is important. Best to handle what i want with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be something you want to do in PHP not MySQL. This will allow for it to display properly for both html (browser) and non html renderers (cli). The reason this works in phpMyAdmin is because it uses [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert new lines (`\n`) to html breaks (`<br>`).

Example:

```
echo nl2br($row['description'];
```

Your code may be different this is just assuming $row is a single row from the results.